# Where can I download ONVIF Device Test Tool?

Tags: onvif

I didn't find the test tool download address on the onvif official website, and it seems that arbitrary registration is not allowed. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Only members of ONVIF can download the test tool.

[Here](https://www.onvif.org/join-us/membership-levels/) you can find the different membership levels.